# Parsec for primes and fibs

Tags: haskell, parsec

I decided to spend some time working with parsec. I've written some code to check for primality and for whether something is a Fibonacci number. I'm mainly hoping for feedback on readability, but if you have any performance tips I'd be interested in those as well.

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Error
import Control.Applicative hiding ((<|>))

toXTerminatedAs :: Int -> String
toXTerminatedAs = end . parse (manyAccum acc digit) "" . show
  where acc digit cur = concat (replicate 10 cur) ++ toAs digit
        toAs digit    = replicate (fromEnum digit - 48) 'a'
        end (Left _)  = error "I can't deal with negative numbers, sorry"
        end (Right x) = x ++ "x"

isLeft :: Either a b -> Bool
isLeft (Left _) = True
isLeft _        = False

fib :: Int -> Bool
fib = not . isLeft . parse (fibParser "a" "") "" . toXTerminatedAs

fibParser a b = char 'x' <|> (\_ -> fibParser b (a++b)) =<< string a

prime :: Int -> Bool
prime = isLeft . parse (char 'x' <|> primeParser "a") "" . tail . toXTerminatedAs

primeParser x = (\c -> try (many1 (string (c:x)) *> char 'x') <|> primeParser (c:x)) =<< char 'a'
```

`toXTerminatedAs` is pretty ugly, but I haven't been able to think of any improvements. As the name/signature implies it turns a number `n` into `n` `'a'`s followed by an `x`.

`prime` works for all natural numbers, but it returns `True` for `0`, and I'm not really sure what to do about it besides hard-coding it in somewhere.

Comment: My honest opinion is that this is both a poor way to learn about parsing and an incredibly baroque way to write a primality test, why don't you try writing a CSV parser or something instead? I can't for the life of me understand what you're trying to do here or why it would involve Parsec. This is taking me some serious effort to read because it is just so *weird*.

Comment: @bisserlis yeah, some of it is kind of strange. The `fibParser "a" ""` might look wrong. (Like it should be `fibParser "" "a"`) but since the offsets between fibs are fibs shifted right by 1.5, you have to extend the sequence a bit to the left and use 1,0 as your starting values. And the reason why I drop the first character of the value in `prime` is that I need to start by dividing into 2's, but my `primeParser` only consumes one `'a'` at a time.

Comment: @bisserlis If you think it's bad enough that it couldn't attract useful answers I'll delete it.

Comment: You seem to have missed @bisserlis 's main point, genisage.  You have conflated two unconnected things in both your premise and your code.  The notion of mixing parsing *into* arithmetic is just bizarre.  And we can't work out *why* you have chosen to do this because *how* you are doing it seems to make no sense at all.

Comment: `prime 0 = false` isn't naughty "hard coding", by the way.  It's using pattern matching to deal with an edge condition.  Although you need to deal with negative numbers as well, so it should really be 
`prime x | x < 1 = false
         | otherwise = your stuff here`

Answer (score 2):

## Parsers are for parsing

This is probably the strangest primality test I've ever seen. So for those that want to write their own primality test, please don't use this approach.

Almost all your functions can be written without a `Parser`. `toXTerminatedAs` is probably the best example:

```
toXTerminatedAs :: Int -> String
toXTerminatedAs n = replicate n 'a' ++ "x"
```

That's easy to read, *and* more likely to be correct. Either way, I assume you know that, so let's get started with the actual review.

## Try not to shadow existing names

We return to `toXTerminatedAs`:

```
toXTerminatedAs :: Int -> String
toXTerminatedAs = end . parse (manyAccum acc digit) "" . show
  where acc digit cur = concat (replicate 10 cur) ++ toAs digit
        toAs digit    = replicate (fromEnum digit - 48) 'a'
        end (Left _)  = error "I can't deal with negative numbers, sorry"
        end (Right x) = x ++ "x"
```

We have three `digit`s here. Two of them are function arguments, but the first one is `Parsec`'s `digit` function. That's misleading. Use `d` or another name that's not already in use. Alternatively, import `Parsec` qualified or `as P` to show the difference more clearly.

## Use the standard library

We stay at `toXTerminatedAs`. `fromEnum digit - 48` isn't that clear to someone who doesn't know `Enum` instances or `48` well. But `digitToInt` shows its intend very well. It's provided by `Data.Char`:

```
import Data.Char

-- ....

toXTerminatedAs :: Int -> String
toXTerminatedAs = end . parse (manyAccum acc digit) "" . show
  where acc d cur     = concat (replicate 10 cur) ++ toAs d
        toAs d        = replicate (digitToInt d) 'a'
        end (Left _)  = error "I can't deal with negative numbers, sorry"
        end (Right x) = x ++ "x"
```

[`isLeft`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:isLeft) is provided by `Data.Either`, so no reason to implement it yourself.

Also, try to avoid `++` in recursive functions or accumulators, as it turns \$\mathcal O(n)\$ algorithms into \$\mathcal O(n^2)\$ ones.

## Encapsulate often used functionality in a function

You often use `parse parser ""`. That's somewhat error prone as you can accidentally forget the file name.

Instead write a small function that takes care of the `SourceName` for you:

```
parse' :: Stream s Identity t => Parsec s () a -> s -> Either ParseError a
parse' p = parse p ""
```

While we're at it, we add a

```
parseViaX p = isLeft . parse' p . toXTerminatedAs
```

## Add type signatures

`parseViaX` is missing its type signatures because I don't know the ones of `fibParser` and `primeParser`. *Always* add type signatures to top-level bindings. Not only will it serve as *minimal* documentation, but it will also make sure that the compiler does not infer too general types or types you didn't expect.

## Document complicated expressions

`fibParser` and `primeParser` should get some documentation.

## Bottom line

Don't mix parsing and arithmetic, at least for arithmetic tests. It's messy and hard to read. Both `fib` and `prime` are easy to write without any parsing at all.

If you were going for code obfuscation: kudos to you, that was brilliant.